# spam e-mail on @ubuntu.com address

Tags: email, ubuntu-email-address

my @ubuntu.com e-mail address is a forwarding address, so I don't have server side control of incoming spam address to that address.

Client-side spam filtering is not very effective.

Anyone know what can be done to reduce this problem? I'm getting about 10 e-mails per day or more that end up in the inbox from my @ubuntu address.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend enhancing your client side spam filtering. My ubuntu email for example is forwarding to my gmail account and with that I get the full range of benefits from the Google account. I do not believe you or I will get any "filtering" support on the ubuntu email part because it just serves as a forwarding address as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Someone also mentioned setting something up on my e-mail server side. I am not certain how to do that, but I guess the question has been answered about the filtering support from launchpad or wherever the ubuntu.com addresses are maintained.